# Running method regularly at fixed points in time

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, timer

I'm working on a mechanism for an Azure cloud service and I'm looking for a way to call a certain method at fixed points in time:
- hourly -> 00:00, 01:00, etc
- dayly
- monthly

Besides of this, I managed to run a method every minute, but this is relative to the time the timer started

```
Thread threadToRun = new Thread(RunPeriodically(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).Start);

private static async Task RunPeriodically(TimeSpan interval)
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(interval);
        MethodToRun();
    }
}
```

This is part of an internal customer throttling mechanism which has to run on a separate thread.

Can all this be done on the same thread?

Best regards,
Remus

Comment: Azure webjobs is what you are looking for, or Azure Finctions

Comment: I don't think that's a viable solution for what I need, because the method I need to call updates some storage tables with data from an internal dictionary.

Comment: well, you could reinvent the wheel, or use services designed to do specifically this

Comment: The reason why I don't use webjobs isn't because I don't want to, but because I can't accomplish what I need with them...

Comment: Have you looked at Quartz.Net library (http://www.quartz-scheduler.net)? We use it for our Cloud Services project to run things on a periodic basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we solved the same issue by implementing a job timer class ( see below ) which handles a timer and fires at fixed point. 
I removed a lot of our code, should still be working.

What is done:
We create a timer which fires every second (can be every millisecond, too, if you need more precision).

We calculate the fix points we want the class to fire, when the timer is started by the Start Method (in this example every full minute, see interval).

At every timer event (which occurs every second started randomly), we check, if the next full minute is completed and then do what we want to do, increasing last execution to the next full minute we need it to execute.

In our example, when we want to fire, the JobTimer Class fires an event, which somebody who wants to act at those fix time points can subscribe to. But feel free to implement it any way you want.

```
using System.Threading;

using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

internal class JobTimer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly object _objectLock = new object();
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim timerLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    private DateTime lastExec = DateTime.MinValue;
    private Timer _timer;

    public JobTimer()
    {
        this._timer = new Timer(1000);
        this._timer.Elapsed += this.TimerEvent;
    }

    private event EventHandler JobDueEvent;

    public void Start()
    {
        if (_timer != null)
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
        }

        this._timer = new Timer(1000);
        this._timer.Elapsed += this.TimerEvent;
        this._timer.Start();

        var interval = 1;
        this.lastExec = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddMinutes(
           (Math.Floor(currentTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes / interval) + 1) * 
           interval).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this._timer.Stop();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Dispose();
    }

    private void TimerEvent(object timerInfo, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            this.timerLock.EnterWriteLock();
            if (lastExec.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)) < DateTime.UtcNow)
            {
                lastExec = lastExec.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
                // DO WHAT YOU WANT TO DO WHEN THE TIMER FIRES
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            this.timerLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take you console applications as is and deploy it as a webjob.
you can easily schedule it there when you deploy your console app.
please read this for details - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs

if you use azure functions and try to move current console jobs, you may have to do some changes.